# Which block manufacturer made this type of person in the 80s

Tags: minifigures, compatibility, clone-brands

I always thought this was LEGO, and played with it in my LEGOs my whole life (got this in the 80s) but found out recently that it is not LEGO. What brand is it? Who made it? He can hold lego tools, etc, and he has holes in his feet and can be stood on lego bricks. I have several friends with this type person who thought it was LEGO as well.

[image: non-lego LEGO type person]

Answer (score 7):

He's made by Tyco as part of their "Super Blocks" range

[image]

You can see the guy on the label.

Answer (score 3):

That figure is a Tyco Super Blocks minifigure.

I can't find any sets that your figure came in, but you can see in the following picture that the soldiers are the same proportion and style as your figure.

[image]

Unfortunately, Tyco Super Blocks is one of the oldest LEGO-clone brands, so there's not a lot of information on their product on the internet.

Comment: I had a bucket of Tyco bricks as a kid, and it came with the minifig the OP posted.  It may have come in sets, but my bucket was just the general "use your imagination" bucket of 500 or so pieces.  http://s3item.bookooinc.netdna-cdn.com/s400_478e0c9ebadfd64537eae47475689.jpg